# SwiftUI toolbar multiple items compression resistance

Tags: swiftui, layout, toolbar

I have a toolbar with user info (leading alignment) and some buttons (trailing):

```
view
    .toolbar {
        ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
            VStack {
                Text("...")
                Text("...")
            }
        }
        ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
            // buttons
        }
    }
```

Normally looks like this:
[image]

But if the text is really long it takes up all the space and doesn't leave anything to the buttons. Like this:
[image]

What I need is to specify compression resistance for buttons, so they always have enough space and text just takes what's left. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a bug of `.navigationBarLeading` placement, as a workaround it is possible to use `.principal` with spacer to align to the left of text is short

Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

[image: demo1]
[image: demo2]

```
ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {   // << here !!
    HStack {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Cosmic Serenity asdlkf ;asdfj kas;dlkf a;sdlfk asdkj")
            Text("Unreality")
        }
        Spacer()    // << here !!
    }
}
```